# How to format a JSON string to a readable output in QT

Tags: json, qt, formatting, string-formatting

I have a JSON string

```
{
"FirstName": "John",
"LastName": "Doe",
"Age": 43,
"Address": {
    "Street": "Downing Street 10",
    "City": "London",
    "Country": "Great Britain"
},
"Phone numbers": [
    "+44 1234567",
    "+44 2345678"
]
}
```

in QString variable.
I found (somewhere here in Stackoverflow) a way to format XML:

```
QString responseData = "";
responseData = networkResponse->readAll();

QString formattedXMLResponse;
QDomDocument input;
input.setContent(responseData);
QDomDocument output(input);
QTextStream stream(&formattedXMLResponse);
output.save(stream, 2);

ui->outputTB->setPlainText(formattedXMLResponse);
```

But this code works fine just for XML.
Any thoughts how JSON can be formatted?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[QJsonDocument](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qjsondocument.html) takes a format to its [toJson](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#toJson) function, allowing you to specify either a [compact or indented format](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#JsonFormat-enum).

Assuming you have your JSON in a QJsonObject called jsonObj:-

```
QJsonDocument doc(jsonObj);
QString jsonString = doc.toJson(QJsonDocument::Indented);
```

Or, from a QString:-

```
QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonString.toUtf8());
QString formattedJsonString = doc.toJson(QJsonDocument::Indented);
```

Comment: It's just that I spent around 10 minutes to find out WTF Qt is trying to tell me.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Qt 4, you can use [QJson](http://qjson.sourceforge.net/) lib.

In this case the usage will be as following:

```
QJson::Parser parser;
bool ok;

QVariantMap result = parser.parse (responseData, &ok).toMap();
if (!ok) {
  qFatal("An error occurred during parsing");
  exit (1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to bring up the old thread, but that would be the best solution:

Example json object:

```
QJsonObject json;
    json["name"] = "Hakan";
    json["age"] = 25;
    json["address"] = QJsonObject{{"street", "Sarıyer"}, {"city", "İstanbul"}};

printJson(json);
```

Formatter:

```
void printJson(QJsonObject json){
    QJsonDocument doc(json);
    QString jsonString = doc.toJson(QJsonDocument::Indented);
    qDebug() << jsonString.toStdString().c_str();
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "address": {
        "city": "İstanbul",
        "street": "Sarıyer"
    },
    "age": 25,
    "name": "Hakan"
}
```